# Tampermonkey js/jquery/ajax how to add a sleep?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tampermonkey

For a page like
https://www.converto.io/?v=EbuYMynCWV8,
I have a Tampermonkey script to automatically:

1. Choose mp4 format
2. Click CONVERT button.

It works, but sometimes maybe it's too fast and finally I get mp3 format download links.
So now I want to put in a sleep time between the two steps. Test result is the code only finishes first step. Any idea?

My code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _ConverTo, Automatically select mp4
// @match    https://www.converto.io/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".format-select:has(option[value=mp4])", selectFinickyDropdown);  //------ step 1,choose mp4 format------

function selectFinickyDropdown (jNode) {
    var evt = new Event ("click");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    jNode.val('mp4');

    evt = new Event ("change");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    setTimeout("secondStep()", 10000);    //--- sleep 10s then step 2,click CONVERT button -------
}

function secondStep() {
    waitForKeyElements (".convert-btn", clickbuttonconvert);
}

function clickbuttonconvert (jNode) {
    var evt = new Event ("click");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes and parens from the `setTimeout` call, the first parameter is supposed to be the function itself.

```js
setTimeout(secondStep, 10000);
```

See [the setTimeout reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: Perfect! Search result can be so wrong! Thanks you very much for once more help, sir.

Comment: I really don't think that's a problem @user2650501. See this: http://jsbin.com/terijagado/edit?html,output You can still use the same way, which you had initially.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, auto-eval'd code often fails in a userscript versus a webpage/console.  Depends and this very common syntax error/typo could well be the problem.